# How is HTML converted into machine language

Tags: html, compilation

I have this doubt for some time. I know when we write a C/C++ program, it is first compiled into assembly language(after going through a number of steps) and is then converted into machine language, which finally gets executed on machine. How is a code written in HTML finally gets converted into machine language ? Is this the procedure : HTML is parsed by the browser ( don't know how), and browser finally converts it to machine language ( through the use of some inbuilt compiler ? ). Can anybody throw some light on it ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML is not converted into "machine language" in the sense in which you're thinking (when you compare it to C/C++).  HTML can be parsed by any program. How that program deals with it is entirely up to the author of that program.  In the case of the browser, which is compiled, it looks at the HTML and parses it and acts on it in some way. Obviously everything is running in the processor as bytes in memory, so, in that respect it eventually winds up being byte code, but again, this is very different from "compilation".

The primary difference in semantics is that when a program is compiled, the byte code are actual instructions that the processor acts on.  Whereas what's happening here is that the HTML data is simply being viewed as ascii bytes that the parser program reads in and then deals with in one way or another.  It would deal with a paragraph of written text the same way. The information isn't telling the processor to do anything directly. It's instructions for the intermediate layer that is the program reading them (again, in your case, the browser).

Comment: how symbols(?,-,+,=,>,<,/) converted into binary?

Comment: "Whereas what's happening here is that the HTML data is simply being viewed as ascii bytes that the parser program reads in and then deals with in one way or another." ---- Here, when you said PARSER PROGRAM, in which language is the parser program written, does it depend on the Browser?

Answer (score 2):

The HTML is parsed and an in-memory data structure that represents the HTML document is created. The browser then walks that data structure and renders it on the screen. The HTML is treated as data and is not executed in the way that the text of the source of an application is executed.

Comment: Ok, So in which languages are modern browsers written?

Answer (score 1):

HTML is interpreted, and not translated to machine code. The browser interprets the tags and knows what to do with them. The it performs the necessary actions: formatting some text, loading images, etc..

You can imagine as if you follow a recipe. You read the instructions and then perform the necessary actions yourself, but the recipe is never doing anything on it's own. This is different with languages like C or C++ where the code is actually translated into code that the machine can execute directly.

Comment: This is why we have the "browser wars", because different browser recognize certain different tags, and even interpret some tags differently from other browsers! This is also why you should always keep your browsers up to date!

Comment: At some point, html IS translated into machine code. The difference is that it's markup that tells the browser which browser code - and by extension which machine code - to run. All programming is a series of translations.

Answer (score 1):

It's not. HTML is not a programming language, there's a reason why it's called hyper text **markup language**.
It's interpreted by the browser (and that's why the same page sometimes behaves differently).

Answer (score 1):

HTML is not complied into into machine language as it does not execute instructions.

The HTML file is not compiled, it is read by the browser and then the browsers draws the described elements onto the screen which makes HTML data that the browser uses then code.

As an example, Say you have a c++ application that reads a text file and then draws a number of shapes on the screen. Say the text file looks something like this:

```
Draw Red Circle
Draw Green Box
Draw Yellow Box
```

Your application would read this file and then draw the shapes on the screen. This is very similar to how HTML is working except HTML is more complicated.